# ¿Se debe utilizar guion en "no-trivial" o se escribe sin él? ¿Y en general?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

Cuando quiero hablar de algo que **no** tiene una propiedad, pero decirlo de manera "afirmativa" (si es que eso significa algo), ¿es correcto usar un guion o no?

Por ejemplo:

> Sólo nos interesan las propiedades de sistemas **no-triviales**.

¿Es correcto ese guion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Según la Real Academia Española ([ver ítem (4) aquí](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=vvMk91OVTD6CnaLO7C)), cuando "no" se antepone a sustantivos o adjetivos abstractos, denotando inexistencia de lo designado por ellos, no se utiliza guion:

- Es partidario de la *no violencia*.
- Su actitud *no beligerante* le granjeó las simpatías de todos.

La RAE dice expresamente que ese "no" se escribe separado y sin guion intermedio. Esto se debe a que "no" es una palabra independiente, no un prefijo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @fedorqui, por la supresión del tilde en "guion". Mi única excusa es que nací entre 1884 y 2010 (http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/guion-se-escribe-sin-tilde/), de ahí mi tendencia a seguirlo usando, jajaja.

Comment: Jajaja yo también pertenezco a ese rango y me sigue costando

Comment: @fedorqui Hablando de tendencias que uno tiene como hablante, observo que tiendo a usar "el tilde" (tal vez por asimilarlo a "el acento"). A pesar de que el DRAE me contradice y decreta que es actualmente femenino ("la tilde"), este artículo que acabo de encontrar indica que ambos son válidos: http://periodistas-es.com/la-tilde-el-tilde-3084

Comment: Pues da para otra pregunta el tema: el [Mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) nos muestra que hasta 1817 se consideraba masculino, luego "amb." (¿ambiguo? ¿ambivalente? en todo caso, entiendo que válido en ambos géneros) y a partir de 1925 predomina más el femenino.